# How to read one component of ArrayType stored in HDF5

Tags: c++, c, hdf5

I have an HDF5 dataset on file, which was written using an `H5::ArrayType` for `double[3]`. The `DataSpace` is one-dimensional (`rank=1`) with `ndat` entries (each of type `double[3]`).

Now I want to read only the second, say, of each `double[3]` into a 1D buffer of `double`s. How can I do that?

If instead, the `DataSpace` was 2D with dimensions `{ndat,3}`, I could simply use the hyper slab selection method to pick out the middle element in the second dimension. Can I do that here too? How?

I'm happy with answers in C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I experimented around with this and found that this is **not possible**, which I consider a **limitation of HDF5**. Essentially, HDF5 treats data types as elementary and does not break them up. Thus, for HDF5 `std::array<double,3>` written with `H5::ArrayType` and `double[3]` written with `H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE` are fundamentally different: the former cannot be read into the latter or vice versa.

So the only solution is to **avoid H5::ArrayType** and use multi-dimensional dataspaces instead.